# Как выборочно отключить JS в Хроме?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

То есть, вопрос не в том, что бы отключить JS в настройках браузера, а в том, как быть, когда тебя занесло в гости к хакеру, и он не отпускает тебя со своей страницы, подсовывая бесконечные поп-апы.

В ФайрФоксе у меня стоит плагин Web Developer, которым можно отключить любой скрипт на странице, а в Хроме, увы нет.

Казалось бы, такая функция должна быть в браузере на самом видном месте.. однако я даже в консоли её не обнаружил. Или не там искал..

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на такой сайт. Аж интересно стало.

Comment: галка же вроде есть - запретить алерты с сайта. (в самом попапе)

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Shift+J -> F8
Первая комбинация открывает инструменты разработчика, вторая — нажимает на паузу в выполнении скриптов во вкладке «Scripts».

Comment: F8 работает только когда открыта вкладка Sources. А по умолчанию открывается Console.